# Преобразование списка словарей

Tags: python

Имеется список словарей следующего вида:

```
a = [
{'animal': {'cats': {'шотландец': 1}}, 'id': 1}, 
{'animal': {'dogs': {'овчарка': 1}, 'fish': {'окунь': 1}, 'cats': {'сфинкс': 1}},'id': 2}, 
{'animal': {'birds': {'синица': 1}, 'fish': {'сельдь': 1}}, 'id': 3}, 
{'animal': {'dogs': {'овчарка': 1}, 'birds': {'воробей': 1}}, 'id': 4}
....]
```

Необходимо преобразовать его в следующий вид (учитывая, что брать нужно только ключи  'cats', 'dogs', 'birds':

```
[{"word": 'шотландец', 'count': 1, 'id': [1]},
{"word": 'овчарка', 'count': 2, 'id': [2, 4]},
{"word": 'сфинкс', 'count': 1, 'id': [2]},
{"word": 'синица', 'count': 1, 'id': [3]},
{"word": 'воробей', 'count': 1, 'id': [4]}]
```

Подскажите, как это можно сделать?
Пыталась использовать следующий код, но не выдает нужный результат и не могу понять в чем проблема:

```
attribute = ['cats', 'dogs', 'birds']
animals = []

for i in range(0, len(a)):
   for key in a[i]:
     if key == 'animals':
        for attr in attribute:
            an = a[i][key].get(attr, {})
            animals.append(an)
            resw = []
            for key, value in an.items():
                result["entity"] = key
                result["count"] = value
            resw.append(result)
            
results = [x for x in named_entities if x]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно сделать так:

```
initial = [
{'animal': {'cats': {'шотландец': 1}}, 'id': 1},
{'animal': {'dogs': {'овчарка': 1}, 'fish': {'окунь': 1}, 'cats': {'сфинкс': 1}},'id': 2},
{'animal': {'birds': {'синица': 1}, 'fish': {'сельдь': 1}}, 'id': 3},
{'animal': {'dogs': {'овчарка': 1}, 'birds': {'воробей': 1}}, 'id': 4}
]

animals = dict()

for obj in initial:
    for animal in obj['animal']:
        if animal not in ('cats', 'dogs', 'birds'):
            continue

        name = list(obj['animal'][animal].keys())[0]
        count = obj['animal'][animal][name]

        if name not in animals:
            animals[name] = {'word': name, 'count': 0, 'id': []}

        animals[name]['count'] += count
        animals[name]['id'] += [obj['id']]

res = list(animals.values())

print(res)
```

если предполагается, что внутри зверья много кличек (а то в примере только 1), то тогда так:

```
animals = dict()

for obj in initial:
    for animal in obj['animal']:
        if animal not in ('cats', 'dogs', 'birds'):
            continue

        for name, count in obj['animal'][animal].items():

            if name not in animals:
                animals[name] = {'word': name, 'count': 0, 'id': []}

            animals[name]['count'] += count
            animals[name]['id'] += [obj['id']]

res = list(animals.values())
```

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь! Да, предполагается наличие большого количества кличек, просто пыталась сократить список, чтоб было наглядней

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, а как исправить ситуацию, когда в каких то словарях встречается более 1 словаря с одинаковым ключом, например так: initial = [
{'animal': {'cats': {'сфинкс': 1}, 'birds': {'воробей': 1}, 'cats': {'манкчин': 1}}, 'id': 1},
{'animal': {'dogs': {'овчарка': 1}, 'fish': {'окунь': 1}, 'dogs': {'корги': 1}},'id': 2},
{'animal': {'birds': {'синица': 1}, 'fish': {'сельдь': 1}}, 'id': 3},
{'animal': {'dogs': {'овчарка': 1}, 'dogs': {'шпиц': 1}, 'cats': {'манкчин': 1}, 'birds': {'воробей': 1}}, 'id': 4}
]. Здесь сфинкс(1), овчарка(2), овчарка(4) пропускаются

Comment: мне кажется словарь с двумя одинаковыми ключами - это ОЧЕНЬ ПЛОХО, потому что один ключ (который первый) не войдет в словарь: `data = {'xxx': 1, 'yyy': 2, 'xxx': 3}` получим только `{'xxx': 3, 'yyy': 2}`, т.е. вы такой словарь можете и написать, но алгоритм получит на вход уже исправленный

Comment: суть в том, что эти данные я получаю со стороннего сервера, и я не могу изменить входные данные

Comment: я понимаю, но сам питон правит словарь, не пользователь, а как вы получаете? json в виде строки?

Comment: да, выглядит так же, как переменная initial

Comment: ну вот вы попробуйте свой текст `initial = .... print(initial)` запустить и увидите, что одного ключа нет, хотя при инициализации он присутствует

Comment: я так и делала) а нельзя, например, рассматривать каждый словарь отдельно и преобразовывать его так же в список словарей? например {'animal': {'cats': {'сфинкс': 1}, 'birds': {'воробей': 1}, 'cats': {'манкчин': 1}}, 'id': 1} преобразовать в [{'animal': {'cats': {'сфинкс': 1}, 'id': 1}
{'animal': {'birds': {'воробей': 1}, 'id': 1}
{'animal': {'cats': {'манкчин': 1}}, 'id': 1}]?

Comment: ну если не в виде словаря, а в виде списка, то можно что-то попробовать, но структура будет совсем другой

Comment: извините, не могли бы Вы пожалуйста помочь с решением этой проблемы, если знаете как? если честно, я не так давно занимаюсь программированием и не знаю как это реализовать

Comment: для начала надо понять как именно передаются данные - в каком формате?